# Duplicate Manifest error

Tags: android, debugging, android-manifest

When I run my android code I get this error

```
Error:(10, 14) error: duplicate class: com.myapp.application.app.Manifest
```

the error show in

```
D:\Code\app\build\generated\source\r\debug\com\myapp\application\app\Manifest.java
```

I removed the whole "generated" folder inside the "D:\Code\app\build\" yet it got regenerated again once I run the code and get the same error about duplicated Manifest

How can I fix this?

Comment: put your manifest file here

Comment: I think you are using a library project which also contains an android manifest, that can cause this error.

Comment: did you try to invalidate cache? In android studio file->Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Qandil, what i have to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got an impossible error in my debug/Manifest.xml.

1. Undo recent change.
2. "Build / Clean Project"
3. Close Android Studio, reopen. Did not work.
4. In the end I moved the files, deleted the project, started a new, and copied the files to the new project.

   That solved my problem.